# Upper and lower bound on different of ${\rm erf}(\frac{x+c}{b})-{\rm erf}(\frac{x-c}{b})$

Tags: real-analysis, error-function

I am trying to find a good upper bound on
 \begin{align*}
f(x)={\rm erf}\left(\frac{x+d}{b}\right)-{\rm erf} \left(\frac{x-d}{b}\right)
\end{align*}
here $d>0$

I know that $f(x)$ is symmetric around origin so one bound would be $f(x) \le f(0)$.

But after plotting the function I realized there  should be abound of the form
\begin{align*}
f(x) \le a e^{-|x|^n/c}
\end{align*}
where $a,n,c>0$.

It's easy to verify that I should be $a=2$ but what about $n$ and $c$?

Answer (score 1):

Note:
I added a more accurate upper bound
at the end,
but it may not
be computational useful.

Since
$erf(x)
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-x^2}dx
$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&={\rm erf}\left(\frac{x+d}{b}\right)-{\rm erf} \left(\frac{x-d}{b}\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{(x-d)/b}^{(x+d)/b} e^{-t^2}dt\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-d/b}^{d/b} e^{-(t+x/b)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-d/b}^{d/b} e^{-t^2-2tx/b-(x/b)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-d/b}^{d/b} e^{-t^2-2tx/b}dt\\
&<\frac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-d/b}^{d/b} e^{-2tx/b}dt
\quad\text{(since } e^{-t^2} < 1)\\
&=\dfrac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \dfrac{e^{-2tx/b}}{-2tx/b}\big|_{-d/b}^{d/b}\\
&=\dfrac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \dfrac{e^{2xd/b^2}-e^{-2xd/b^2}}{2tx/b}\\
&=\dfrac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}\sinh(e^{2xd/b^2})}{\sqrt{\pi}tx/b}\\
\end{array}
$

This might be reasonable
for small
$d/b$.

---

Here is a 
more accurate 
upper bound:

$f(x)
=\frac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-d/b}^{d/b} e^{-t^2-2tx/b}dt
$.
Since
$e^t \ge 1+t$,
$e^{t^2} \ge 1+t^2$,
so
$e^{-t^2} \le \frac1{1+t^2}$.

Therefore

$$f(x)
\le\frac{2e^{-(x/b)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-d/b}^{d/b} \dfrac{e^{-2tx/b}}{1+t^2}dt
$$

However,
according to Wolfram Alpha,
$$\int \frac{e^{a x}}{1+x^2} dx 
= \frac{-1}{2 i e^{-i a}} (e^{2 i a} Ei(a (x-i))-Ei(a (x+i)))+constant
$$

(where $Ei$ is the exponential integral)
so I don't know how useful this is.

Comment: I think. You have type in $\sinh$