# What is $\int \frac{e^{a x}}{1+x^2} dx $?

Tags: special-functions, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

In my answer to another question
(here: [Upper and lower bound on different of ${\rm erf}(\frac{x+c}{b})-{\rm erf}(\frac{x-c}{b})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289674/upper-and-lower-bound-on-different-of-rm-erf-fracxcb-rm-erf-frac/1289707#1289707)),
I came up with this integral:
$\int \frac{e^{a x}}{1+x^2} dx 
$.
I was not able to
evaluate it,
so I asked Wolfram Alpha,
which came up with this:

$$\int \frac{e^{a x}}{1+x^2} dx 
= \frac{-1}{2 i e^{-i a}} (e^{2 i a} \mbox{Ei}(a (x-i))-\mbox{Ei}(a (x+i))) +
\mbox{constant}
$$

where $\mbox{Ei}$ is the exponential integral.

Is there a simpler form of this?

I don't know if this will help,
but the actual integral
in my answer
has symmetric limits around zero,
so its form is

$$\int_{-b}^b \frac{e^{a x}}{1+x^2} dx 
$$

Simplifying this would be sufficient.

Comment: The WA result just follows from writing $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ as $\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{x-i}-\frac{1}{x+i}\right)$. Why do you expect there is a sneaky way of re-writing a generic exponential integral?

Comment: one iteration by parts will convert this to $\int e^{ax} \tan^{-1}(x)dx$ but not sure this is simpler...

Comment: Jack: Thanks. Duh. I should have seen that. The appearance of Ei was discouraging, although I was hoping that the symmetric bounds might have simplified things.

Comment: Letting $x=\tan u$, we have $\displaystyle\int_{-c}^ce^{\large a\tan u}~du$.

Comment: And then? (6 more to go)